# Mathjax issue - Math symbols not appearing at all

Tags: jekyll, travis-ci, github-pages, mathjax

I have an issue with Mathjax on my website (hosted on Github pages, compiled by Travis CI).

There are some symbols which are not displayed at all, while they work fine when I run the website locally. For instance, the expression `$p\subseteq 2^{\kappa}$` is not displayed at all.

The webpage is this:
https://st-dimopoulos.github.io/posts/2018/09/sacks-supercompact/

and the line where the problem I mentioned appears is in the 5th paragraph.

I am not really experienced with programming, can someone tell me some steps to find where the problem lies?

Comment: The HTML source has ` <script type="math/tex">% <![CDATA[ p \subseteq 2^{< \kappa} %]]></script> ` and MathJax will honor % as TeX comments. This may be due to `<` which is problematic in an HTML context. Perhaps using MathJax's `\lt` macro instead will avoid the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem actually! It was my first time using mathjax and I was not aware of the strict syntax.

Comment: Glad that worked. It's not really MathJax's fault -- < starts tag names in HTML (and markdown accepts inline html). If you leave < and > in the file, then all kinds of things can go wrong at parsing time, long before MathJax gets to it. See https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-in-html-documents for more information.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks.